# how to save and remove a canvas state?

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize

I want to give a div, which containing a canvas, visual controllers when resizing it with jQuery's resizable() function.

I mean by saying 'visual controllers' these 8 black squares which appear when you click on an image that allow you to resize the image like this example :

[image: an image with visual controllers]

I have written the following function that draws 8 squares around the div. When clicking on the div, it gives the aimed visual appearance. When clicking on the div again it removes the 8 squared and removes the resizable() function. It works fine **but** when resizing the div and clicking on it again to remove the 8 squares it doesn't remove them.

I need to save the canvas state before clicking on before it applies the drawings and restore it when clicking on the canvas again.

```
$(document).on("click", "canvas", function(eg) {
    var thisCanvas = $(this).attr("id");
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById(thisCanvas);
    var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasSelected(thisCanvas, ctx);
});
```

When the user clicks of the canvas it fires the following function:

```
function canvasSelected(theCanvas, ctx){
    var ctxWidth = $("#"+theCanvas).width();
    var ctxHeight = $("#"+theCanvas).height();
    if($("#"+theCanvas).hasClass("bordering")){
        ctx.restore();
        $("#"+theCanvas).addClass("defaultBorder");
        $("#"+theCanvas).removeClass("bordering");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(ctxWidth- 6,0,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(ctxWidth/2,0,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(0,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(ctxWidth- 6,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(ctxWidth/2,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(0,ctxHeight/2,6,6);
        ctx.clearRect(ctxWidth- 6,ctxHeight/2,6,6);
        $("#"+theCanvas).resizable("option", "disabled", true);
    }else{
        ctx.save();
        $("#"+theCanvas).removeClass("defaultBorder");
        $("#"+theCanvas).addClass("bordering");

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillRect(ctxWidth- 6,0,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillRect(ctxWidth/2,0,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        // bottom rects..
        ctx.fillRect(0,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillRect(ctxWidth- 6,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillRect(ctxWidth/2,ctxHeight- 6,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        // middle rects
        ctx.fillRect(0,ctxHeight/2,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillRect(ctxWidth- 6,ctxHeight/2,6,6);
        ctx.fill();
        $("#"+theCanvas).resizable();
        $("#"+theCanvas).resizable("option", "disabled", false);
    }
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DevelopSmith/hUPVQ/1/)

Comment: Try binding to the stop event of the resizable widget, then call canvasSelected for there. See http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is how the canvas is being re-sized via `resize()`. The size is being changed in terms of how large the canvas is, but it will not change the size of the coordinate system. Your initial width and height of 550x350 stay the same.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/hUPVQ/4/)**

All I did was add the following to your `canvasSelected` event,

```
// get the canvas element
var canvas = document.getElementById(theCanvas);
// change the pixel dimensions to match the css width and height.
canvas.width = ctxWidth;
canvas.height = ctxHeight;
```

This ensures the pixel dimensions will be updated as well. Just remember its usually a bad idea to re-size the canvas element using CSS as you will get unexpected results.

The above will cause you to have to redraw your graphics however. So another method is just to keep track of the original width, and height, of your canvas and use those values like the following fiddle does.

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/hUPVQ/3/)**

In this example I just made height and width global so they would always be referenced, however I imagine you can use the demo provided to come up with a better way of keeping track of the original height and width of the element.

Also note, jQuery's `width()` and `height()` are not the same as calling `width` and `height` on the canvas element. jQuery's methods re-size the element using its style properties.

Comment: the `width` and `height` is NOT the same in each canvas. I tried to get them from the `$(document).on()` function which calls the `canvasSelected()` function and send the values as parameters but it doesn't work.

Comment: well I have updated it to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DevelopSmith/hUPVQ/5/). I have done three changes. the `$(document).on()` , improved the removing of the `resizable()` and added a line of code to add a fake class to prevent the `$(document).on()` function from recalling `width()` and  `height()`